# Ruby self execute

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to make this shorter?

```
string = string.split
```

Ruby has some `!` functions that make that, but how about this?

What i want something like string.split! But not to add additional String class method

Comment: How short do you want? Like a=b?

Answer (score 4):

You would have to write a method for your `self` class that does more or less exactly what your line of code there did.

```
def split_keywords!(sep = ' ')
    @keywords = @keywords.split(sep)
end
```

The problem with this is you are changing what `keywords` is (from a `String` to an `Array`) so you will have to write all other methods that interact with `keywords` so they will work whether it is a `String` or an `Array`.

The reason there is no `split!` method for `String` is because it would involve changing the variable from one class to another in mid-method.

```
# This will raise a SyntaxError
class String
    def split!(sep = ' ')
        self = self.split(sep) # Causes self to become an Array mid-method
    end
end
```

So, to answer your question, no, there isn't a shortcut for what you are wanting to do but I would recommend rethinking your approach unless `keywords` is able to act like both a `String` and an `Array` with no worries.

Comment: omfg … I do not asking to create new methods. It's does't matter WHAT THE CLASS is self and does't matter what the keyword instance is!

Comment: i'm asking for a shorter construction like a += 1 is shorten to a = a + 1

Comment: I understand your question and @peter and I have done the best we could with such a short and undetailed question. However, what I'm telling you in my answer is that what you are wanting is not possible. When it comes to a shorter construction involving a method with a bang at the end, like `split!`, there isn't one if the bang method would change the class from say `String` to `Array`, which is what a `split!` would do and which is why there is none.

Answer (score 1):

just using `"key words".split` will give you the array `["key", "words"]`
Used in a class as your self suggests makes it like

```
keywords = "key words"

class String
  def -@
    self.split
  end
end
p -keywords #=> ["key", "words"]
```

By the way, did you know `"[%s]" % keywords` produces the same result ?

Comment: I'M NOT ASKING TO CREATE NEW METHODS! omg

Comment: please don't be rude, we try to help, see first part of my answer, can't be shorter, next time be more clear, the use of self in your only line of code suggests you work from a class method

Comment: ok sorry for that man :) Actually this is part of rails activerecord class. So, any way it's dent matter, read it as keywords = keywords.split. So i've asked for built-in method or construction like a += 1 ... oh... like keywords = keywords.uniq may be implemented like keywords.uniq!, you know. So i'm asking actually does ruby have construction like += but for class methods ? Because ! methods not for each. Thx

Comment: You probably should have added an ActiveRecord tag to your question.

Comment: It's doesn't matter man :D It's just instance, no matters if it main object instance of instance of class

Comment: don't know if i understand what you ask, but changed my answer, take a look, you can do this trick only with operatorsallrady defined in Ruby